# Как сделать sticky блок через fixed?

Tags: javascript, html

чтобы поведение осталось, как сейчас
....

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: red;
}

header+section {
  padding-top: 18px;
}

.elem {
  position: sticky;
  top: 18px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<header>
  header
</header>

<section class="block">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam unde possimus incidunt eos nobis modi voluptatibus ea. Architecto doloribus optio molestias quia eum vel sunt, pariatur excepturi quod obcaecati odit.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis minus, vero repudiandae aut suscipit iusto debitis. Hic pariatur id cumque aliquam cupiditate dolorem sit, possimus tempore iusto, deserunt, libero impedit.</p>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam unde possimus incidunt eos nobis modi voluptatibus ea. Architecto doloribus optio molestias quia eum vel sunt, pariatur excepturi quod obcaecati odit.</p>
 
</section>

<section class="elem">
  <p>sticky block</p>
</section>

 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis minus, vero repudiandae aut suscipit iusto debitis. Hic pariatur id cumque aliquam cupiditate dolorem sit, possimus tempore iusto, deserunt, libero impedit.</p>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam unde possimus incidunt eos nobis modi voluptatibus ea. Architecto doloribus optio molestias quia eum vel sunt, pariatur excepturi quod obcaecati odit.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis minus, vero repudiandae aut suscipit iusto debitis. Hic pariatur id cumque aliquam cupiditate dolorem sit, possimus tempore iusto, deserunt, libero impedit.</p>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam unde possimus incidunt eos nobis modi voluptatibus ea. Architecto doloribus optio molestias quia eum vel sunt, pariatur excepturi quod obcaecati odit.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis minus, vero repudiandae aut suscipit iusto debitis. Hic pariatur id cumque aliquam cupiditate dolorem sit, possimus tempore iusto, deserunt, libero impedit.</p>
```

Comment: А зачем, то есть какая цель? И что именно у тебя не получается?

Comment: @yar85, жалуются что при стики иногда баги

Answer (score 1):

```js
const header = document.querySelector('header'), 
      section = document.querySelector('.elem'),
      targetEl = section.querySelector('p'), 
      topOffset = -header.scrollHeight - targetEl.scrollHeight;

const iobs = new IntersectionObserver(([entry]) => {
  targetEl.classList.toggle('is-fixed',
    entry.boundingClientRect.top <= header.scrollHeight
  );
}, { root: document.body, rootMargin: `${topOffset}px 0px 0px 0px`, });
iobs.observe(section);
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
html,
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; }
body { overflow-y: auto; }

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px; right: 0; left: 0; 
  background-color: red;
}

header+section { padding-top: 18px; }

.elem { min-height: 1rem; }
.elem p { background-color: yellow; }
.elem p.is-fixed { position: fixed; top: 2px; right: 0; left: 0; }
```

```html
<header>
  header
</header>

<section class="block">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam unde possimus incidunt eos nobis modi voluptatibus ea. Architecto doloribus optio molestias quia eum vel sunt, pariatur excepturi quod obcaecati odit.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis minus, vero repudiandae aut suscipit iusto debitis. Hic pariatur id cumque aliquam cupiditate dolorem sit, possimus tempore iusto, deserunt, libero impedit.</p>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam unde possimus incidunt eos nobis modi voluptatibus ea. Architecto doloribus optio molestias quia eum vel sunt, pariatur excepturi quod obcaecati odit.</p>
 
</section>

<section class="elem">
  <p>sticky block</p>
</section>

 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis minus, vero repudiandae aut suscipit iusto debitis. Hic pariatur id cumque aliquam cupiditate dolorem sit, possimus tempore iusto, deserunt, libero impedit.</p>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam unde possimus incidunt eos nobis modi voluptatibus ea. Architecto doloribus optio molestias quia eum vel sunt, pariatur excepturi quod obcaecati odit.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis minus, vero repudiandae aut suscipit iusto debitis. Hic pariatur id cumque aliquam cupiditate dolorem sit, possimus tempore iusto, deserunt, libero impedit.</p>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam unde possimus incidunt eos nobis modi voluptatibus ea. Architecto doloribus optio molestias quia eum vel sunt, pariatur excepturi quod obcaecati odit.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis minus, vero repudiandae aut suscipit iusto debitis. Hic pariatur id cumque aliquam cupiditate dolorem sit, possimus tempore iusto, deserunt, libero impedit.</p>
```